# Testing with Espresso in Android error

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I'm working with espresso for testing. I'm following [Espresso Intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html)

and problem happened when I try to work like this site. First is validateIntentSentToPackage method:

```
public void validateIntentSentToPackage() {
    user.clickOnView(system.getView(R.id.callButton));
    intended(toPackage("com.android.phone"));}
```

Android Studio display error at "user" and "system". I don't understand this error what does this mean.

Second is activityResult_IsHandledProperly method:

```
public void activityResult_IsHandledProperly() {
    Intent resultData = new Intent();
    String phoneNumber = "123-345-6789";
    resultData.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);
    ActivityResult result = new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);

    intending(toPackage("com.example.unittestdemo")).respondWith(result));
    onView(withId(R.id.pickButton)).perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.phoneNumber).check(matches(withText(phoneNumber)));}
```

Android Studio display error java.lang.NullPointerException and in line `intending(toPackage("com.example.unittestdemo")).respondWith(result);`

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Android Studio display error at "user" and "system". I don't understand this error what does this mean.

I guess, you don't have previously declared these variables.

I don't see any logs or whole code of this testing class, so I can only recommend you to check this [example](https://github.com/appoll/Espresso21/blob/95fa0f4806053af1ce09ecf9284d0f8af1ac0d80/app/src/androidTest/java/enough/paul/espresso21/ChooserIntent.java)

Here you would find all methods which you're looking for in one file.

Also please visit [Google Samples - Espresso Testing repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso)